# How to update the listbox in real time in excel using VBA

Tags: excel

I have a listbox which contains the data present in the rows of a table in excel. If some contents of the table are updated while running the script, the update only gets reflected in the listbox if I run it again. How to reflect the changes in real time?

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DataStorage")
Dim i As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Me.ListBox1.Clear

For i = 2 To Application.CountA(sh.Range("BP:BP"))
    Me.ListBox1.AddItem sh.Cells(i, 68).Value
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Write codes on `sheet_change` event.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to share more details, e.g. code you have written. Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to enhance your question.

Comment: Create a separate sub that fills the listbox. Call this sub from UserForm_Activate and from the worksheet_change-event